# Smallest leaf node in min heap using heap operations only

Tags: data-structures, heap

How can I find the smallest leaf node in min Heap using heap operations only?

Comment: Is it a binary heap?

Comment: You should probably specify what operations you mean by "heap operations".  If you mean 'add', 'peek-min', and 'remove-min', then there is no way to find the smallest leaf using just those.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a binary heap you can take [floor(n/2)]+1 when n is the number of elements on the heap It would give you the left most leaf node.

Comment: It is binary but there may be other leaves smaller than the left most one

Comment: Why the leftmost node? It could be the rightmost node as well. There is no order on the children node of a given node.

Comment: It is binary but there may be other leaves smaller than the left most one https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~adamchik/15-121/lectures/Binary%20Heaps/heaps.html

Comment: @MonicaCharles You can check the leaf nodes by [floor(n/2)]+1 to n and compare them to find the smallest leaf node.

Answer (score 0):

The only requirement in the min heap is that each node is smaller than its parent. Thus, there is no order between leaves, which means that such leaf can be any node among the second half of the array which is used to store the heap. So, one should traverse *n/2* elements (second half of the array) and find the smallest one.

Comment: Thanks I had the same idea but it is required to find the smallest one using heap operations

Comment: Why selecting one-by-one element of the second half of the array is not the heap operation? When the heap is created from bottom-up, the similar sequence of operations is executed (taking elements from the second half of the array and comparing them against their parents until the right position is found).